# Using json encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, encode

I am trying to use json encode for the first time and need some insight to what I am doing wrong.

It should look like this:

> { teams : [ ["2147483647", "9"],["2147483647", "6"],["2147483647", "4"],["11",   "2147483647"],["5", "2147483647"],["12", "8"],["10", "3"],["2147483647", "7"], ], results : [ [ [[0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 1],[1, 0],[1, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],], [[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],], [[0, 0],[0, 0],], [[0, 0],[0, 0]] ] ] }

But the data being returned looks like this:-

> {"teams":[["2147483647","10","5","12","11","2147483647","2147483647","2147483647"],["7","3","2147483647","8","2147483647","4","6","9"]],"results":[["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]}

Code:

```
public function getAutoCompleteData($tournID, $db)
{

    $max           = $this->max($tournID);
    $one           = $this->tourn_info("1on1", $tournID);
    $total_matches = $max;
    $after_matches = $max / 2;

    $matches = $db->query($this->select("*", "matches", "leagueID='{$tournID}' AND league='tourn'"));
    while ($row = $db->fetchAssoc($matches)) {

        $clan1 = $this->getname($row['clan1'], $tournID, "tourn", $ac = NULL, 1, 1, $wc2 = 0);
        $clan2 = $this->getname($row['clan2'], $tournID, "tourn", $ac = NULL, 1, 1, $wc2 = 1);

        if ($row['matchno'] <= $after_matches) {
            $clan_one[]  = $row['clan1'];
            $clan_two[]  = $row['clan2'];
            $score_one[] = $row['score1'];
            $score_two[] = $row['score2'];
        }
    }

    $data = array(
        'teams' => array(
            $clan_one,
            $clan_two
        ),
        'results' => array(
            $score_one,
            $score_two
        )
    );

    return $data;
}
```

Where it shows teams, it should close the bracket `]` every two teams?
Hope someone can help.

Comment: But the first code is not JSON...

Comment: Where is your class? `$this` refers to a class. to make a Constructor use `public function __construct(){}` within the class.

Comment: Your code is very confused. Variables $one, $clan1, $clan2 are never used.You are creating an array with two items, each having two items. Exactly what your JSON is showing.

Comment: Have you tried using the `json_encode()` function?

Comment: I would assume it is your database output or something in the following way you process your database output creates the unexpected output. json_encode simply draws PHP arrays out as if they were JSON. It appears that you also get unexpected new numbers, etc., so I would try and print the database content using var_dump and see exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this will fix your problem, but it may help you to understand PHP.

```
class mustBeAClass{
  protected function max($tnid){
    // must have this function - can be public for outside method use
  }
  protected function tourn_info($typ, $tnid){
    // must have this function - can be public for outside method use
  }
  protected function getname($arg0, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, $arg6 = 0){
    /* must have this function - can be public for outside method use
    notice that $arg6 is how you assign default to arguments */
  }
  public function getAutoCompleteData($tournID, $db){
    $db->open();
    $max = $this->max($tournID); $one = $this->tourn_info("1on1", $tournID);
    // what is the point of this ---->>>> $total_matches = $max;
    $after_matches = $max / 2;
    // notice query issue below
    $matches = $db->query("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE leagueID ='$tournID' && league='tourn'"));
    // while loop has problems
    if($matches->num_rows < 1){
      die('You have no matches');
    }
    else{
      while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()){
        $clan1 = $this->getname($row['clan1'], $tournID, 'tourn', null, 1, 1, 0);
        $clan2 = $this->getname($row['clan2'], $tournID, 'tourn', null, 1, 1, 1);
        if($row['matchno'] <= $after_matches) {
          $clan_one[]  = $row['clan1'];
          $clan_two[]  = $row['clan2'];
          $score_one[] = $row['score1'];
          $score_two[] = $row['score2'];
        }
      }
      $data = array(
        'teams' => array($clan_one, $clan_two),
        'results' => array($score_one, $score_two)
      );
    }
    $matches->free(); $db->close();
    return $data;
  }
}
$cls = new mustBeAClass; 
echo json_encode($cls->getAutoCompleteData($tournId, $db));
```

Of course use the correct values for `$tournId` and your `new mysqli(/*args*/)` for `$db`.